# How To Save Cookies As A String Using Selenium And C#?

Tags: c#, selenium

So far I achieved getting all the cookies of a website (which I want. I don't need nor want specific cookies) using this code:

```
var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;

// write full path txt file
using (StreamWriter fs = new StreamWriter(@"demo.txt", true))
{
    foreach (var cookie in cookies)
    {
        fs.WriteLine(cookie.ToString());
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to read from the file and insert the values cookie by cookie using the following code:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\flame\Desktop\demo.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(line);
    MessageBox.Show(line.ToString());
}
```

However, this does not work unlike the first lines of code. Even my first code does not do what I actually want, which is to save all cookies of a given website as a single string and then add all the cookies using this single string. I don't want to save the cookies in a file.

If you know how to do it, which you probably do, if you chose to click on this question, I would appreciate any information and example codes.

In addition, I am aware of the use of data-dir. However, this is not what I am looking for since I want to save the cookies as a string, since this is the requirement of my project.

Comment: I understand that you mention Selenium Driver as you are using it to get the cookies, but once you get them in your "var cookies" you no longer use Selenium and it may come to the matter of knowing what type your 'var cookies' is?  Is it a list of string for instance? Could you provide the type of that 'var' at runtime?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Even though the question is a bit unclear i will try to give you a solution to your problem.

If understood correct you need to convert the `OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie` to `string` so you could serialize the retrieved cookies into a json string and store this json into a variable for later use. Now if you want to set this string (of cookies) as the new cookies you must deserialize it back to `OpenQA.Selenium.Cookie`.

For this purpose i created two extension methods for cleaner code

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetCookiesAsString(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        var cookies = driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies;
        return System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(cookies, new JsonSerializerOptions { WriteIndented = true });
    }

    public static void SetCookies(this IWebDriver driver, string json)
    {
        var cookies = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json)!;
        foreach (var c in cookies)
        {
            string name = c.Name;
            string value = c.Value;
            string domain = c.Domain;
            string path = c.Path;
            DateTime? expiry = c.Expiry;
            bool secure = c.Secure;
            bool isHttpOnly = c.IsHttpOnly;
            string sameSite = c.SameSite;

            var cookie = new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry, secure, isHttpOnly, sameSite);

            driver.Manage().Cookies.AddCookie(cookie);
        }
    }
}
```

And you can use these methods as below:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments( "--headless");
using var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/");

var initialCookies = driver.GetCookiesAsString();
Console.WriteLine(initialCookies);

driver.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

Console.WriteLine($"Cookies exist: {driver.Manage().Cookies.AllCookies.Any()}");

driver.SetCookies(initialCookies);

var modifiedCookies = driver.GetCookiesAsString();
Console.WriteLine(modifiedCookies);
```